# iterating json elements in c#

Tags: c#, json, dynamic

I have got the following json returned from a service :

```
{
   responseHeader: {
      status: 0,
      QTime: 1
   },
   spellcheck: {
     suggestions: [
       "at",
       {
            numFound: 2,
            startOffset: 0,
            endOffset: 2,
            suggestion: [
               "at least five tons of glitter alone had gone into it before them and",
                "at them the designer of the gun had clearly not been instructed to beat"
            ]
       },
       "collation",
       "(at least five tons of glitter alone had gone into it before them and)"
    ]
  }
}
```

1. I need to create in c# a List of what inside the "suggestion" element. What is the best way?
2. What are the elements not surrounded by "". Shouldn't all json element be surrounded by ""?
   Thanks.

**EDIT**:
This is based on dcastro answer

```
 dynamic resultChildren = result.spellcheck.suggestions.Children();
 foreach (dynamic child in resultChildren)
 {
       var suggestionObj = child as JObject;
                if (suggestionObj != null)
                {
                    var subArr = suggestionObj.Value<JArray>("suggestion");
                    strings.AddRange(subArr.Select(suggestion =>               suggestion.ToString()));
                }

 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problems with your json string:

1. yes, all keys should be wrapping with double quotes
2. your "suggestions" structure doesn't make any sense... Shouldn't you have an array of well-defined "suggestion" objects? Right now, you have an array of a mix of strings ("at", "collation") and other json objects (the object with numFound, etc).
3. What is the purpose of having a string "at" there? It's not a json key, it's just a string...

**Edit**

This should work:

```
       JObject obj = JObject.Parse(json);
       var suggestionsArr = obj["spellcheck"].Value<JArray>("suggestions");

       var strings = new List<string>();

       foreach (var suggestionElem in suggestionsArr)
       {
           var suggestionObj = suggestionElem as JObject;
           if (suggestionObj != null)
           {
               var subArr = suggestionObj.Value<JArray>("suggestion");
               strings.AddRange(subArr.Select(suggestion => suggestion.ToString()));
           }
       }
```

Assuming the following json string:

```
{
   "responseHeader": {
      "status": 0,
      "QTime": 1
   },
   "spellcheck": {
     "suggestions": [
        "at",
        {
            "numFound": 2,
            "startOffset": 0,
            "endOffset": 2,
            "suggestion": ["at least five tons of glitter alone had gone into it before them and", "at them the designer of the gun had clearly not been instructed to beat"]
        },
        "collation"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: this looks like a SOLR response - so is correct other than the fact that the propetry names / keys should actually be quoted, actually - suggestion does usually have more data - as in an array of objects you're right

Comment: Correct. What I am asking is for a recommendation of how to parse the SOLR answer.

Comment: Brilliant. I made some improvements and I will add it to the question.